# What's the difference between a direction field and a slope field?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning about direction fields in differential equations with a two-dimensional system. How is this different from regular slope fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling either term turns up the other as a synonym, so presumably they are not different.  (These kind of terms aren't usually given formal definitions, since they're just graphical representations of a differential equation, which *is* something that has a definition.)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree, they are synonymous, albeit not identical terms. Interestingly, no one seems to argue that they are clearly distinct terms.
But,..., more interesting, to me at least, is why confine the use of these terms (whichever you prefer) to differential equations and dynamical systems. Any function in real space has a direction/slope field, defined by the grad f(•). I.e., the function of interest does not have to be a differential equation; it can be any real function in 2-dim or higher space. Accordingly, grad f(•) generates the slope/direction/"greatest change" field, which shows the direction of greatest change in the domain of independent variables.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment, not Answer:* A Google search of "slope field" registers about 62,000 hits.  A Google search of "direction field" registers about 120,000 hits.  That would suggest that "direction field" is more popular.  However, the Wikipedia page for "direction field" has no content and automatically directs to "slope field" which is where the content is.  Similarly, the free math program Geogebra (which I use heavily in my classes) has an automatic feature SlopeField[  ].

Therefore, I am going to stick to calling them "slope fields."